# conda build is omitting data file sub-directories, even though setup is including them

Tags: setuptools, conda, setup.py

I'm using `conda build` with a Python project that includes documentation, via a *MANIFEST.in* file and the `package_data` option to `setup()`:

In *MANIFEST.in*:

```
recursive-include pybert/doc/_build/html *
```

In *setup.py*:

```
setup(
  name='PyBERT',
  version=pybert.__version__,
  packages=['pybert',],
  package_data={'pybert': ['doc/_build/html/*',]},
```

I'm finding that while `setup` includes the subdirectories of my *html* directory:

```
(pybert) Davids-Air-2:PyBERT dbanas$ tar xjf ~/anaconda/conda-bld/noarch/pybert-2.4.1-py_0.tar.bz2 -C ~/tmp/

(pybert) Davids-Air-2:PyBERT dbanas$ ls ~/tmp/site-packages/
PyBERT-2.4.1-py2.7.egg-info     pybert

(pybert) Davids-Air-2:PyBERT dbanas$ cat ~/tmp/site-packages/PyBERT-2.4.1-py2.7.egg-info/SOURCES.txt | grep 'html'
pybert/doc/_build/html/.nojekyll
pybert/doc/_build/html/genindex.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/index.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/intro.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/modules.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/objects.inv
pybert/doc/_build/html/py-modindex.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/search.html
pybert/doc/_build/html/searchindex.js
pybert/doc/_build/html/_modules/index.html
{8 more from _modules/ snipped.}
pybert/doc/_build/html/_sources/index.rst.txt
pybert/doc/_build/html/_sources/intro.rst.txt
pybert/doc/_build/html/_sources/modules.rst.txt
pybert/doc/_build/html/_static/ajax-loader.gif
{21 more from _static/ snipped.}
pybert/doc/_build/html/test_dir/dummy.html
```

The set of files actually installed by `conda build` is missing the subdirectories of *html* (as well as the *.nojekyll* file):

```
(pybert) Davids-Air-2:PyBERT dbanas$ ls -A ~/tmp/site-packages/pybert/doc/_build/html/
genindex.html           intro.html              objects.inv             search.html
index.html              modules.html            py-modindex.html        searchindex.js
```

Note that the *test_dir/* subdirectory was added by hand, to ensure that it wasn't just the '_' prefix of the other subdirectory names that was fouling things up. Apparently, it wasn't, since *test_dir/* is also missing.

Comment: dumb question, but using the package_data above will this then lead to the files being "installed" into the same `..anaconda2/envs/pybert/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybert/` subdir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package_data` requires us to list all subdirectories explicitly, alas. See an example at https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/commit/20d035deaf0f0b6e5d3d5163a3f15281b5dc6c95#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298R102

So you should write

```
package_data={'pybert': [
    'doc/_build/html/.nojekyll',
    'doc/_build/html/*',
    'doc/_build/html/_modules/*',
    'doc/_build/html/_sources/*',
    'doc/_build/html/_static/*',
    'doc/_build/html/test_dir/*',
]},
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I, actually, had to write: 'doc/_build/html/_modules/*/*', as well, in order to pick up one sub-sub-directory.

Answer (score 2):

> Although this is about setuptools, *not* conda -- reason why I came here (i.e, question title)...

Actually, you can define sub-directories copy with `*/*` syntax. 
In your case, the following should work:

```
setup(
  ...
  package_data={'pybert': ['doc/_build/html/*/*',]},
  ...
```